# clearInterval not working properly in simple example

Tags: javascript, html, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {update()}, 1000)

function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(timer);
}
```

and my html:

```
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work? Would be great to get a few pointers, I'm thinking its a problem with scope?

Comment: Works. http://jsfiddle.net/6XmKy/ Make sure `myStopFunction()` is global.

Comment: if `myStopFunction` defined inside another function>

Comment: @Musa Nope - It's global, yet it still doesn't work...

Comment: Does the console show any error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Program isn't exactly clear as I can't really figure out your function scope from this small example.

However, one possibility is that you have declared the setInterval function inside another function, that is being called multiple times.

In this case, multiple Intervals are being set and only the last Interval to be set would be cleared with the clearInterval.

If this is your problem, the solution would be to declare timer as a global variable and then clearInterval(timer) every time before you setInterval.

I wrote an example below

```
var timer;
function mySetFunction(){
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = setInterval(function() {update()}, 1000);
}

function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(timer);
}
```